# How can I create a new android View in a for loop?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Is there a way to add objects such as EditText's in a for loop (loop count depending on user input).

Basically, I want the program to add a certain amount of EditText based on the number that the user inputs.

I'm new to java and Android studio so this code could be completely wrong but maybe someone can help me out.

```
public class ThirdActivity extends Activity {

private static EditText NumberOfGarments;
private static CheckBox GarmentChecker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);

    NumberOfGarments = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number_of_garments);
    final Integer NoOfGarments = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(NumberOfGarments)); //Convert string to int
    GarmentChecker.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    for (int GarmentCount = 1; GarmentCount <= NoOfGarments; GarmentCount++){
                        //Not sure what to put here
                    }
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Outside of your loop have an `ArrayList` of, say, `EditText` objects. Inside your for loop you can then create however many you need and add them to your ArrayList for posterity.

Comment: Why the -1?  This is a perfectly valid beginner question.  Poor wording of a question should be expected when people are new.

Answer (score 0):

In an activity, you can create an EditText programmatically with this constructor :

```
EditText editText = new EditText(this); //"this" must be an Activity
```

Then you must add it to the activity layout as a child of a ViewGroup.

```
ViewGroup editTextsContainer = (ViewGroup)findViewViewById(R.id.editTextsContainer);
editTextsContainer.addView(editText);
```

Answer (score -2):

outside loop you have to instantiate your object and create object inside your loop for example-

```
Player[] players = new Player[10];
for(int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
          players[i] = new Player();
}
```

Comment: What if OP needs more than 10 `Player` objects? What if they need only 2?

Comment: then op should use list or arraylist

Comment: Is that not a better solution then? Just giving hints on how to improve your answer :)